# Choosing to start a specific duplicated Service when a duplicate namespace exsists on the device

Tags: android, android-intent, package

I have a strange situation which I freely admit, is not ideal,

I have two different apps, each that use an `Android Library Project`. This library project contains a `Service` which doesn't have any special intent filters defined in the `AndroidManifest` of the container project.

How is it possible for me to start the service of one of these apps rather than the other, given that they have the same namespace (from external to both apps).

Note, using `Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.utils.URIReceiverService");` will randomly start one, or the other `Service` randomly.

Answer (score 1):

> How is it possible for me to start the service of one of these apps rather than the other, given that they have the same namespace (from external to both apps)

Well, by default, you can't, since those services will not be exported.

If they are exported, you can craft a `ComponentName`, which identifies the package of the *app*, plus the fully-qualified class name of your service, and use that with `startService()` or `bindService()`. Of course, *anyone else* can craft a similar `Intent`, so think through your security.